# How can I find out the code DRIMSeq uses to make dmplotProportions objects?

Tags: rna-seq, r, rna-splicing, ggplot2

I'm using DRIMSeq to do some analysis but I'd like to make my own figures from the results ideally using what they've done as a base.

I'm trying to find how they make their ggplot objects in the function `plotProportoins` but when I use `findMethods('plotProportoins')` it ends up with a method `dmPlotProportoins`.

It says in the manual that it's a *ggplot* object but I can't seem to find how they make it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can look at the source code of the package and see how they create the object.

Comment: What's the best way to do it? findMethods gives me the source code of the function but how can I get the code of the whole package? (sorry if the answer should be obvious)

Comment: In the tar ball you have the source code of the package.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing. Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious how they have done it as well, so here expanded @Liopis comment :

```
wget http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/src/contrib/DRIMSeq_1.6.0.tar.gz
tar -zxf DRIMSeq_1.6.0.tar.gz 
# if you need to find it, or use grep
# find DRIMSeq -name "dm_plotProportions.R"
less DRIMSeq/R/dm_plotProportions.R
```

Comment: This is planned to change and be able to look at the code thorough a web interface